# Find the family of functions each of whose derivative is the cube of the function itself.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find the family of functions each of whose derivative is the cube of the function itself.

The answer is $2x + y^{-2} = c$.

My thought process was $y = f(x) \Rightarrow y' = f(x)^3 + c$ but I don't know how to get that answer.

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: @almagest could you explain why that is the setup, after performing it I can see that is the correct answer but I don't understand why that is the setup. More specifically, why 1/y^3 vs y^3.

Comment: Because $dy$ and $y^3$ are on opposite sides of the starting equation. Oh, the minus is an error. I intended to put one in front of both integrals. Recall that a standard technique for simple ODEs is to try to put everything involving $y$ on one side, and everything involving $x$ on the other.

Comment: You really have $$f'(x) = f(x)^3$$ which is separable.

Answer (score 1):

$f'(x)=f(x)^3 \implies \frac{dy}{dx} = y^3 \implies \frac{1}{y^3}dy = dx \implies \int y^{-3} dy = \int 1 dx \implies \frac{y^{-2}}{-2} = x +c \implies -\frac{1}{2y^2} = x+c \implies y = \pm
\sqrt{-\frac{1}{2(x+c)}} $ for any constant value of $c$.